# When exactly would a DLL use a different heap than the executable?

Tags: c++, dll

I know that if your DLL  static links against a different version of the runtime then it creates its own heap. It will also if it is instructed to make a heap. Under these circumstances, it is unsafe for the DLL to delete what the exe allocated. In what cases does this NOT apply (as in, it is safe for the DLL to delete what the exe allocated)? Is it safe if both the exe and the DLL static link against the same runtime library?

Thanks

basically is there a way where whoever allocates it could just do `addEvent(new DerivedEvent(), FunctorDestroyClass());`

Comment: No. This is why you dynamically link against the runtime. This is the standard behavior (dynamic linking) and the only way recommended by MS. statically linking the runtime just causes headaches. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be reading more into your question than is there, but if you are wanting to know how you can allocate and free memory across DLL boundaries, then you might use something like the following:

```
#define DLLMemAlloc( size ) HeapAlloc( GetProcessHeap(), 0, size )
#define DLLMemFree( mem )   HeapFree( GetProcessHeap(), 0, mem )
```

That might be safer (a partial attempt at future-proofing).  Relying on various build options to guarantee the safety of allocating and freeing across boundaries might lead to problems.

And (also not part of the question), you might re-think whether it is really necessary to be able to do this. It seems like there may be a design flaw if one DLL has to allocate something that another DLL (or executable) has to free.

Comment: It's because I want to do polymorphic timed events, so theres no factory way to do this, and if the user has no way to keep track of time they will not know when to free it which is why the DLL needs too.

Comment: I agree.  I don't think you can allocate on one side and free on the other and sleep well at night, even if it works fine at the moment it will bite you in the ass one day.

Comment: @Milo DLL can expose a cleanup interface and EXE can use it to free instead of just using a free() call.

Comment: @MK yea I agree, but how else can I do polymorphic timed events then?

Comment: @MK Do you have an example of this? Could I use a functor and pass it into the timed event constructor?

Comment: @MK basically is there a way where whoever allocates it could just do addEvent(new DerivedEvent(), FunctorDestroyClass());

Comment: @Milo Maybe you could overload new and delete operators to use the desired memory functions.

Comment: @Mark Wilkins would a funtor that is a class exposed to everyone work? so whoever does new also drags in a functor instance?

Comment: using smart pointers (shared_ptr, unique_ptr) you can provide allocator, that will allocate and deallocate at the same place.

Comment: @Milo I may not be understanding the question, but I don't know why a functor would not work implemented that way. It would simply be using memory that anyone can read/write/free.

Answer (score 0):

DLL will get it's own memory manager if you link run-time library statically. You have 3 options: link run-time dynamically, always allocate and deallocate in the same place (either DLL or executable, providing forwarding if necessary), or use 3rd party memory allocator that takes care of this problem.

Comment: So if the DLL links to the runtime of MSVCR80.DLL dynamically, then the exe links to MSVCRT90.DLL dynamically, theres no problem?

Comment: There definitely is if they're not the same version. You shouldn't rely on two modules to have the same heap.

Comment: @Milo there shouldn't be a problem unless you try to allocate on one side and free on the other, but I haven't tried it myself (tm).